# How to force S3 requests to go through cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am very new to S3 and cloud front.

I have a webapp in an S3 bucket. I reroute to that App from a different App. That reroute contains some sensitive information in the querystring, and therefore I only want to accept https requests. 
For that I need cloudfront and want to avoid direct bucket access.

Bucket: `abc.xyz.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
URL: `abc.xyz.com`

I enabled the options `https only` and `Restrict Bucket Access` in cloudfront.

And while that works fine in cloudfront, the original url `abc.xyz.com` doesn't seem to go through cloudfront. `http` is still available and `https` doesn't work.

Is there a way to force access to the bucket only via cloudfront?

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ORIGINACCESSID"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc.xyz.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to setting the **Restrict Bucket Access** to **Yes** in CloudFront, you'll need to edit the S3 bucket policy itself to something like:

(Replace the XXXXXXXXXXXXXX string with the Origin Access ID that was created for you in CloudFront Distribution's Origin)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1476619022974",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1415003054675",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can read more on Using an Origin Access Identity to Restrict Access to Your Amazon S3 Content [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).

Comment: @Moezalez: Have you created an A record (type: ALIAS) in your DNS that points to your CloudFront distribution's domain name instead of your S3 bucket endpoint?

Comment: A record? Is that a cloudfront or s3 thing? I have set a CNAME in cloudfront.

Comment: It is a DNS Service thing (Route 53 or other). CNAME in CloudFront enables you to use your own domain name instead of CloudFront's domain name. You'll also need to point your *abc* host to the CloudFront distribution, not S3 bucket. You can read more here (see bullet no. 7) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: The host? The host is S3 in that case, no? All the files are being served from there.

Comment: If you want to restrict S3 access to CloudFront only, then the host should be the CloudFront distribution not S3, and CloudFront will retrieve the objects from S3 for you (hence the need for the Origin Access Identity).

Comment: I've done all that. The problem is that one still can access the bucket directly and not through cloudfront.